# Why nothing gets printed after while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, println

I am writing a simple bank application. In my program I have used a while loop. In case a user enters wrong input it will re-prompt to enter again.

Now the problem is I am not able to write any `system.out.print` statement after the loop. It always shows error (says: ***unreachable statement***), and eventually the line doesn't get printed out.

**HOW CAN I FIX THIS?**

[*The reason I need to use `system.out.print` because I want to print all the info the user has input.*]

The program I am working on:

```
 package bankapplication;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("WELCOME TO OUR BANK!\n\nPlease give all the inofrmation correctly.");

        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Enter your SSN: ");
        String ssn = input.next();
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Enter your Address: ");
        String address = input.next();
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Enter your telephone nr: ");
        String teleNum = input.next();
        System.out.println("");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Choose an account number for you (Between 5 and 10 positive numbers): ");
            int accNum = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("");
            if (accNum < 0 && accNum > 10 && accNum < 6) {
                System.out.println("Invalid choise!");
            } else {
                System.exit(0);

            }
        }

        System.out.println("Congratulation! Your new account has been created!");
        System.out.println("The following is your account info:\n");
        System.out.println("name: " + name + "SSN: " + ssn + "Address: " + address + "Tele. Num: " + teleNum + "Acc num: " + accNum);

    }

}
```

Comment: Take a deep breath and look at your logical expressin in the `if`: `when the number is less then 0 **and** greater then 10 ...` - at least this will never ever evaluate to true leading to the else branch exiting the program. You'll probably use some `||` operators. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you invoke `System.exit` the entire program exits and the process is terminated. Instead you could replace the `else` statement with:

```
else { break; }
```

That will break the current loop and the rest of the statements will be printed. The keyword `break` simply *breaks the loop*.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `while (true)` loop - a loop which is infinite unless something in the loop breaks out of it. The only line you have that breaks out of the loop is `System.exit(0)`, which will end your program entirely. Therefore it is impossible to reach the code after your loop.

If you mean to break out of the loop in your `else` clause, use a `break` statement instead of exiting the program.

Note however that your `if` condition will never be true.

```
if (accNum < 0 && accNum > 10 && accNum < 6) {
```

`accNum` can never be less than zero *and* greater than 10.

You need to figure out what condition you actually want to check.

Answer (score 1):

the condition

```
(accNum < 0 && accNum > 10 && accNum < 6)
```

can never be acheived , there is no way a number can be negative and >10 at the same time...the System.exit(0) will always be called on first loop.

That and when u call System.exit(0) you are exiting the program not the loop, therefor you will never reach the statement you are talking about .

you should either use

```
break;
```

or if you would like more prestige, put the right condition in the while(condition) ... try not to get used to using break ;